# remote secure_mkdirs failed: Operation not permitted adb: error: failed to read copy response

Tags: android, appium, adb, samsung-galaxy

I am having a mobile with following configurations:

- Model Name: Samsung S22 Ultra
- Model Number: SM-S908E
- Android Version: 12

I enabled developer options and USB debugging and I am able to execute adb devices, adb install filename.apk.

I need to push some bin and python files into the location /sdcard/Android/data/com.company.lc.us.lm/files/.

I am using this command:

> adb push MyFolder /sdcard/Android/data/com.company.lc.us.lm/files/

Following is the error I am getting:

```
remote secure_mkdirs failed: Operation not permitted adb: error: failed to read copy response
```

I had gone through multiple threads with this error. Most of the solutions needs to root the mobile phone. I actually dont want to root my phone as in my remaining samsung phones I am able to  adb push successfully without any error without root.

Had anyone faced this issue? If so please let me know the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to manually create the folder via adb and then push one file to test if it works at all?

Comment: @Robert yes I am able to create a folder at the location /sdcard via abd and adb push is happening into the folder successfully. Also I am able to create a folder inside /sdcard/Android/data using adb . But push is failing , The folder I am pushing has 9 folders with bin files in each of them . Few are getting pushed at some other bin file I am facing this issue.

Comment: I would give `adb-sync` a try, may be it works better as it pushed the files individually.

Answer (score 0):

i had this same error when trying to push a whole directory to an android device. it uploaded the first file in the directory (which took time), but failed immediately when trying to actually create the file on the other end. but it DID create the directory for the file, so the second time the same push command worked without issues.

my workaround is to create the directory first (with adb shell mkdir) before pushing a directory of files to the device. that works flawlessly every time.

this is a very strange and silly bug in adb to be honest.